# JavaScript + Mocha + Allure Ошибка при формировании отчета, когда тест падает

Tags: allure, mocha

Окружение для автотестов:

- JavaScript
- Mocha
- Allure

```
"devDependencies": {
    "allure-mocha": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0"
}
```

Вопрос: когда тест красный (assert не выполнен), Allure адаптер падает при формирование XML репорта с ошибкой:

```
Internal error in Allure: Error: charData should not contain characters not allowed in XML
```

Это происходит даже для самого простого теста с единственным assert:

```
it('Test failure', function () {
    assert.strictEqual(1, 2);
});
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить данную ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

mocha-allure-reporter - старая версия библиотеки.
Лучше использовать allure-mocha в качестве адаптера. allure-mocha генерирует json, а не XML